# How to setup a dependent Texture lookup in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I need to setup a 'dependent texture' such that the return values from one texture lookup are used to determine where to look up from a second texture.

Can you point me to the right gl API calls I would need to do this?

Comment: Are you using the old fixed function pipeline or GLSL shaders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to setup a 'dependent texture' such that the return values from one texture lookup are used to determine where to look up from a second texture.

This can be done using shaders, only.

> Can you point me to the right gl API calls I would need to do this?

You were asking for the API calls: Well here they are:

- `glCreateShader` to create new shader objects
- `glShaderSource` to load the shader source code into the shader objects
- `glCompileShader` to compile the loaded shader sources
- `glCreateProgram` to create a program object
- `glLinkProgram` to link the shader objects into a program
- `glUseProgram` to actually use the shader program created with the above calls
- `glUniform1i` to set the fragment shaders sampler uniforms to the texture units sourced

Also, you were not asking for them, but you need them as well, here are the required GLSL language elements:

- `sampler…` uniforms to bind the texture units to
- The `texture` GLSL function to fetch a texture sample. Use the value of a sampled texture to determine the texture coordinate for the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Like this.

```
uniform sampler2D coord_texture;
uniform sampler2D sampling_texture;
uniform vec2 InvWinSize;

void main(void){
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCord.st*InvWinSize;

    vec2 tex_coord = texture(coord_texture, uv).st;
    vec4 sampled = texture(sampling_texture,tex_coord);
}
```

I accessed the first texture with the screen coordinates, but you can use whatever uv you need, for examples, uv coming from a vertex shader:

```
uniform sampler2D coord_texture;
uniform sampler2D sampling_texture;

in vec2 uv;

void main(void){

    vec2 tex_coord = texture(coord_texture, uv).st;
    vec4 sampled = texture(sampling_texture,tex_coord);
}
```

Comment: Ibasa, I think I am using the old fashioned piepline, the rest of the code involves textures defined by glTexImage2D, glBindTexture, and other such gl commands. There is even a glTexImage3D in my code which I understand is now depracated. This is a very old code that I need to tweak a little. I am basically trying out to find out what is that one directive or command that tells GL to make one texture dependent on another. Thanks.

Comment: @user2654449: What makes you think glTexImage3D was deprecated? Also the other functions you mentioned are part of modern OpenGL as well. And you can't do texture indirections using the fixed function pipeline. You must use shaders.

Comment: @user2654449 yes, my answer is exampe code for the fragment shaders in which to do the dependent texture thing

Comment: Darius, I just checked, TexImage3D is not depracated. Mea Culpa.

Comment: 'glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->ColorLookupIndex);'   

     glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
     glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );    
     glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP );
     glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP );

     glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 256, 256, 0,
                  GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this->ColorLookup );    
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->ColorLookupIndex);'

This is what I was referring to.

Comment: @Datenwolf, dont you have to bind the texture? In the rest of my code, I see TexImage2D followed by BindTexture used repeatedly.

Comment: Yes, you have to bind the texture to a texture unit. However the texture unit just defines the textures used for sourcing the texel samples. The actual indirected sampling is done by a fragment shader program.